# Take Transform3D as input in a macro

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I am creating a macro for a 3D object that needs to be adjusted to the result of a CameraTracker.

Instead of exposing the Transform's properties in the macro's editor, I would like to be able to take a transform as a pipe input. This would make it easier for the macro's user to fine tune the position.

The problem is that I need to pass my 3D object into the transform, which doesn't work if it's not part of the macro. Is there any node that allows me to apply a transform which would take the 3D object & transform as inputs?

[image]